# HTML -- How can I make my navbar stick after scrolling to a certain point on page?

Tags: html, navbar

How can I make my navbar stick after scrolling to a certain point on page? I don't want it to stick immediately after scrolling past it, but rather once I reach another div on the page.

Comment: does the div have to be completely in the viewport? if there are multiple divs on the page does it stick to only the topmost/bottommost one or will it appear on each?

Comment: The navbar will be at the top of the page. I want the user to be able to scroll past it until a specific div has been scrolled down to, and then I want the navbar to be fixed at the top of the page until scrolled back up to. Here is an example: http://zozothemes.com/foody/foody2/index.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  var scrollTop = (window.pageYOffset !== undefined) ? window.pageYOffset : (document.documentElement || document.body.parentNode || document.body).scrollTop;
  if (scrollTop >= document.getElementById("d").offsetTop) {
    document.getElementById("nav").style.position = "fixed";
    document.getElementById("d").style.marginTop = "50px";
    document.getElementById("nav").style.marginTop = "-50px";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("nav").style.position = "static";
    document.getElementById("d").style.marginTop = "0px";
    document.getElementById("nav").style.marginTop = "0px";
  }
}
```

```css
nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  z-index: 100;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 1000px
}
#d {
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <nav id="nav"></nav>
  <div id="d"></div>
</body>
```

When you scroll to the yellow div, the red navbar sticks to the top of the viewport and stays there until you scroll up

Comment: I'm having a small problem. I am using <header> tag for the navbar. How can I reference that tag as opposed to Id?